# Optimizing this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I want to know if there's a way to make this code more efficient please, I am trying to improve my own code but I feel I need feedback, with this part:

```
$(function(){
    $('#buscar').focus(function(){
        if(($(this).val() === '') || ($(this).val() === ' ') || ($(this).val() === 'Buscar...'))
            $(this).val('');
    }).change(function(){
        if(($(this).val() === '') || ($(this).val() === ' ') || ($(this).val() === 'Buscar...'))
            $(this).css({'color':'#999999'});
        else
            $(this).css({'color':'#000000'});
    }).blur(function(){
        if(($(this).val() === '') || ($(this).val() === ' '))
           $(this).val('Buscar...');
    });
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to optimize here?

Comment: not repeat that many times the same if statement, I do that a lot in all of my code =/

Comment: Am I gathering correctly that you're trying to implement a placeholder/watermark script for a search field? Why are you checking for `=== ' '`, what's so special about a single space?

Comment: yes I am =), I am truly impressed by you noticing it haha. // I've had trouble when people send a single space that's why if they leave it empty I just fill it with the default again

Comment: touché @deceze - do you speak spanish?

Comment: I do, why? (i don't know if you're asking me or deceze)

Comment: Properly implementing a placeholder script that doesn't get in the user's way may be a little more complex than this. Personally I'm using the [HTML5 Placeholder jQuery Plugin by Mathias Bynens](http://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin). Also, if you're having trouble with single spaces being send, this is the wrong fix. Also, what about *two* spaces?

Comment: And you didn't try `$.trim`? This: `($(this).val() === '') || ($(this).val() === ' ')` would become this: `$.trim($(this).val()) === ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* ==========================================================
 * speed and readable improvment
 * ========================================================== */
$(function(){
    $('#buscar')
      .bind('focus change blur', function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          if(event.type === 'focus' || event.type === 'change')
            $this
              .iff($this.isEdited('Buscar...'))
                .val('')
                .end();
          else if(event.type === 'blur')
            $this
              .iff($this.isEdited(null))
                .val('Buscar...')
                .end();
      });
});

(function($){
  '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

  $.fn.iff = function( test ) {
    var elems = !test || $.isFunction( test )
      && !test.apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1) )
      ? []
      : this;
    return this.pushStack( elems, 'iff', test );
  };

})(jQuery);

$.fn.isEdited = function(placeholder) {
    if(typeof placeholder !== 'string')
      placeholder = '';

    var val = $(this).val();
    return $.trim(val) === '' || val === placeholder;
};
```

Edited: rewrite the code to add the idear from 'Mohan Ram' (multiple event binding)
Remark: 
  you can use this code also without the "iif"-extension if you like.
  then you must write:

```
if((event.type === 'focus' || event.type === 'change') && $this.isEdited('Buscar...'))
```

Answer (score 1):

***I think this is the simplest way to write your code in optimised way***

```
$(function(){
    $('#buscar').bind('focus change blur' , function(){
  //write ur codes here
});
```

Comment: +1 very good idear. i have change my answer to reflect this and show a sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487662/optimizing-this-javascript-code/4487931#4487931

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like the code below.  It isolates the functions you need (test for empty string, or test for no value or the placeholder text).  Also, I don't believe the `change` function is the right place to change the color; rather it should be in the `focus` and `blur` functions where you also change the value.

Also, if you are simply looking for a placeholder method for an input field, there are many already made for you, where you set the text and the CSS style. Also, HTML 5 has a `placeholder` attribute for this purpose - see http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder.  Some of the better placeholder plugins even use HTML 5 and fall back on JS if it is not supported.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
$.fn.isValBlank = function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == "";
};

$.fn.isInputBlank = function() {
    return (($(this).isValBlank() || ($(this).val() === 'Buscar...'));
};

$(function(){
    $('#buscar').focus(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).isInputBlank()) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css({'color':'#000'});
        }
    });

    $('#buscar').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).isValBlank()) {
            $(this).css({'color':'#999'});
            $(this).val('Buscar...');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were the future and HTML5 were everywhere, or if everybody used only current versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, then you could knock out most of that code and replace it with this:

```
<input name="something" id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar...">
```

But since, as of this writing, it's still the present, you can tighten things up a little like this:

```
function isEdited(el,placeholder){
  placeholder = typeof placeholder == 'undefined' ? 'Buscar...' : placeholder;
  return $.trim( $(el).val() ) === placeholder;
}

$('#buscar').focus(function(){
  if( isEdited(this) )
      $(this).val('');
}).change(function(){
  if( isEdited(this) )
      $(this).css({'color':'#999999'});
  else
      $(this).css({'color':'#000000'});
}).blur(function(){
    if( $.trim( $(this).val() ) )
       $(this).val('Buscar...');
});
```

If you need to do a lot of this, you might consider the jQuery [Placeholder Plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/placeholder). It uses the `placeholder` attribute, so it's HTML5-friendly.

Also,

Answer (score 0):

Having the extra knowledge, thanks to @deceze's insight, I would recommend factoring out most of this logic into a single function. Essentially all these conditions are checking if the field is empty or not.

Also, I am adding a check for any sort of whitespace since a single `" "` is just as irrelevant as two spaces `"  "`.

```
function isTextFieldEmpty(text, placeholder) {
    var onlyWhitespace = /^\s+$/;
    return (text == "" || onlyWhitespace.test(text) || text == placeholder);
}
```

Then you can reuse this function for all the events - `focus`, `blur`, `change`.

```
$(function() {

    // to avoid repeating this text everywhere..
    var placeholder = 'Buscar...';

    $('#buscar').focus(function() {
        if (isTextFieldEmpty(this.value, placeholder)) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });

    $('#buscar').blur(function() {
        if (isTextFieldEmpty(this.value, placeholder)) {
            $(this).val(placeholder);
        }
    });

    $('#buscar').change(function() {
        if (isTextFieldEmpty(this.value, placeholder)) {
            $(this).css({ color: '#999' });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ color: '#000' });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML [**input elements have a `defaultValue`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) property accessible by JavaScript. When talking about placeholder text input values, you can use this to help make code more reusable. This isn't perfect by any means but...

```
$(function(){

    $("input[type='text']").focus(textInputFocusHandler).change(textInputChangeHandler).blur(textInputBlurHandler);

});

function hasUserValue(textInput) {
    return (textInput.value!=textInput.defaultValue && /^\s+$/.test(textInput.value)==false && textInput.value!=="");
}

function textInputFocusHandler(event) {
    if(!hasUserValue(event.target)) event.target.value = "";
}

function textInputChangeHandler(event) {
    if(!hasUserValue(event.target)) event.target.style.color = "#999";
    else event.target.style.color = "#000";
}

function textInputBlurHandler(event) {
    if(!hasUserValue(event.target)) event.target.value = event.target.defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick optimization:

```
$(function(){
$('#buscar').focus(function(){
    var t = $(this);
        var v = $.trim(t.val());
 if(v === '' || 'Buscar...'){
    $(this).val('');
        }
}).change(function(){
    var t = $(this);
        var v = $.trim(t.val());
 (v === '' || 'Buscar...' ? t.css({'color':'#999999'}) : t.css({'color':'#000000'}))
}).blur(function(){
    var t = $(this);
        var v = $.trim(t.val());
    if(v === '')
       t.val('Buscar...');
});
});
```